# restrict constructor access in variadic template class

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I want to create a statically checked builder. Something along these lines:

```
class HasDough;
class HasCheese;

template <typename ... CurrentTypes>
class Pizza {
    public:
        friend Pizza<> startPizzaMaking();

        Pizza<HasDough, CurrentTypes ...> addDough(){
            return Pizza<HasDough, CurrentTypes ...>();
        }

        Pizza<HasCheese, CurrentTypes ...> addCheese(){
            return Pizza<HasCheese, CurrentTypes ...>();
        }

    public: // I want to change to private
        Pizza() = default;
};


Pizza<> startPizzaMaking() {
    return Pizza<>();
}
```

use it like this:

```
int main(){
    auto pizza = startPizzaMaking()
        .addDough()
        .addCheese();

    return 0;
}
```

Now I can go along and check the current types with a disjunction. That way I can make sure everything is added.

My Problem is:
Each step along the way I create a new builder instance and want to pass my current state. For that the constructor should be private and I would use the friend function to obtain a new builder.

How can I restrict access to the constructor to force others to use the factory but internally I can still use it?

[update]

simply making the constructor private doesn't work. The code will expand to something like this:

```
Pizza<HasDough>::addCheese() {
    return Pizza<HasCheese, HasDough>(); // fine with public constructor, not so with private
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different class template specialisations are completely separate classes and have no access to internals of each other. Fortunately there are always friends to save your day.

```
template <typename ... CurrentTypes>
class Pizza {
    public:
        friend Pizza<> startPizzaMaking();

        Pizza<HasDough, CurrentTypes ...> addDough(){
            return Pizza<HasDough, CurrentTypes ...>();
        }

        Pizza<HasCheese, CurrentTypes ...> addCheese(){
            return Pizza<HasCheese, CurrentTypes ...>();
        }

    private: // OK
        Pizza() = default;

        friend Pizza<> startPizzaMaking();    
        // make every specialisation a friend of every other      <=== this here trick
        template <typename ...> friend class Pizza; 
};

Pizza<> startPizzaMaking() {
    return Pizza<>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try once I get to a PC. I already had the friend for the factory though ;)